# how to fix IndexOutOfBoundException() within array list?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

In my program, I use a layered array list to remember properties about buttons (pressing certain buttons are "right" and others are "wrong") where the outer layer depends on the JPanel the buttons are found on and the inner layer is boolean variables who are either true or false. The number of buttons are random though. There is an IndexOutOfBoundsException at the line `while (buttonInfo.get(buttonInfo.size() - 1).get(rightButton) == true) {` so I keep getting stuck on that line but I suspect there's the same problem at `buttonInfo.get(buttonInfo.size() - 1).add(rightButton, true);`.

```
    int numberOfButtons = rnd.nextInt(5) + 2;
    buttonInfo.add(new ArrayList<Boolean>());
    JPanel newPanel = new JPanel();
    newPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 0));
    JLabel panelMessage = new JLabel("Choose one.");
    newPanel.add(panelMessage);
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 5));
    for (int b = 0; b < numberOfButtons; b++) {
        JButton newButton = new JButton(String.valueOf(b));
        newButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(newButton);
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < (numberOfButtons/2); a++) {
        int rightButton = rnd.nextInt(numberOfButtons);
        while (buttonInfo.get(buttonInfo.size() - 1).get(rightButton) == true) {
            rightButton = rnd.nextInt(numberOfButtons);
        }
        buttonInfo.get(buttonInfo.size() - 1).add(rightButton, true);
    }
```

How do I fix the while statement so that it is within bounds?

Comment: If `buttonInfo` is empty, that will try to get the element at index -1. What's the exact error? It will specify the index being passed. Post the full trace.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).
please [add](/help/editing) 
the *complete* error message and 
a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

With this line:

```
buttonInfo.add(new ArrayList<Boolean>());
```

you add only 1 item to the list `buttonInfo`. 
This item is an initialized but **empty** list.  
This list does not get populated (at least in the code you provided). 
So this:

```
buttonInfo.get(buttonInfo.size() - 1).get(rightButton)
```

is equivalent to:

```
buttonInfo.get(0).get(rightButton)
```

whatever is the value of `rightButton` an error will be thrown,  
because `buttonInfo.get(0)` is **empty**.

Comment: Sorry, would you be able to define what you mean by "populated"? Also, if this panel is the first and therefore I would like to save it in the first index of the outer array list, what should I be trying to get instead of `buttonInfo.get(0)`?

Comment: `buttonInfo` is a list of lists. You added an empty list to it. So it contains 1 item and this is `buttonInfo.get(0)`.This item is a list that is **empty** so you can't do: `buttonInfo.get(0).get(0)` because there is nothing in the `0th` position of `buttonInfo.get(0)`.